# Reset Ant Design Upload to its initial state

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to create a function that deletes all those list items which it shows after selecting images, at once rather then deleting them separately.

```
beforeUpload={(file) => {
        handleSetFiles(file)
        return false
    }}
```

```
const handleSetFiles = async (file) => {
    try {
        const code = await getBase64(file)
        setImages((prevFiles) => [...prevFiles, code])
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error Converting image to base 64:", err)
    }
    }
```

By using `beforeUpload` prop upload component does not upload images instantly rather we can upload images manually but it still shows list items like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytPJa.png). I stored those images base64 code in a state `const [images,setImages] = useState([])`and tried to empty the state in a function `handleDelte`

```
const handleDelete = ()=>{
    setImages([])
}
```

which I call on a button click. It remove all items in state but those list items stays in place even I can view them and delete them spearatly.

What I want is when I click on button that calls `handleDelete` function it should remove all those list items and when I select any image again, I should be able to see those list items and have the same functionality of previewing and deleting them separatly.